# Problem with entry.hasDescendants()

Tags: templating, entries, structure

So I have a Structure like that

- Item

  - Subitem | inactive
  - Subitem | inactive

why is `item.hasDescendants()` true ?

How would I do something like that the right way:

```
<li class="{% if nav_item.hasDescendants() %}more{% endif %}">
```

Answer (score 2):

hasDescendants() is only concerned with whether the entry actually has descendants; not whether they are enabled or not.

To determine in an entry has *enabled* descendants, you can do this:

```twig
{% set hasDescendants = entry.descendants.total() %}
```

Or in your case:

```twig
<li class="{% if nav_item.descendants.total() %}more{% endif %}">
```

`entry.descendants` is an alias for [EntryModel::getDescendants()](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getDescendants), which will return a new [ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) prepped to return descendants of `entry`. By default it will only return the enabled ones, like all ElementCriteriaModel’s.

Comment: One would think that `hasDescendants()` and `getDescendants()` behave the same ...

Comment: They serve different needs. `hasDescendants` will just return a binary `true` or `false` depending on whether the entry has any descendants, without any support for parameters that could affect the answer. `getDescendants()` will actually trigger a DB query, so it can afford to accept parameters, and offer the data in different formats, depending on your needs.